# Unable to find element on closed window

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am new to selenium web driver
I am trying to Login to a webpage which leads to auto close the Login page then open the browser in another window, here when i try to click the Logout button in the new page it is saying the error as "Unable to find element on closed window".

Please some one suggest me in how to handle this situation

Regards,
Pavan

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to switch windows.  This link has a good rundown on how you can do this:

[How to switch to the new browser window, which opens after click on the button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9588827/webdriver-switch-to-new-browser-opened-after-click-on-button)

The relevant part for you is this:

```
//Store the current window handle
String winHandleBefore = driver.getWindowHandle();

//Perform the click operation that opens new window

//Switch to new window opened
for(String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()){
    driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
}

// Perform the actions on new window
```

Comment: I have already tried this but it is not worked for my scenario, because the first window will automatically closed on successful login and then i am unable to perform any command on the opened web page.

Answer (score 1):

What happens when you try something like this?

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this the correct solution, but when I tried to run the test case using non - admin instance of Visual Studio 2013 I was getting the ***Unable to find element on closed window*** exception. But when I ran the same case as administrator the test case worked as expected and this exception was not thrown.