# Selenium - close a window with a confirmation alert . C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm automating tests on a web page which pops an Alert window upon clouser using `driver.close()`.
The alert is for confirmation asking if i'm sure and exposes "stay" or "leave" buttons.

Now, when `driver.close()` is executed, the popup shows and `driver.close()` is "stuck", waiting for response, BUT I cannot executed `driver.switchto().alert()` to response (`accept()` or `dismiss()` ) since the driver is waiting...
Working with additional thread didn't help.
Eventually, after a long timeout, close throws an exception....

Any ideas? 
It is so trivial scenario, yet very hard to deal with from code with selenium api.

Comment: Do you want to test that the alert is there? I would first try to call `driver.dispose()` or `driver.quit()` if you don't care about the alert and see if that takes care of it. That being said, if you are calling `driver.close()` intentially to keep the driver alive and just close the current window, this wouldn't be what you want.

Comment: If you want to acknowledge the alert is there, the answer here applies: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29054134/how-to-close-the-browser-by-rejecting-popup-window-in-selenium-webdriver 
Basically just use `((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.close()" );` to close the browser, then you can accept or reject the alert, or check if it's there before calling `driver.quit()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is eventually as **mrfreester** suggested.
Since I want to test the alert as well, I first initiate the Alert by calling the JS for closing the window.
Next, I interact with the alert using web driver.

Step 1:

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.close()" )
```

Step 2:

Wait for the alert and interact (see Java example here: [Alert handling in Selenium WebDriver (selenium 2) with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8244723/alert-handling-in-selenium-webdriver-selenium-2-with-java) )

```
 Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
 alert.accept(); // or alert.dismiss()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just execute following code lines before closing browser (`driver.close()`) to avoid pop-up appearance:

```
IJavaScriptExecutor js = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
js.ExecuteScript("window.onbeforeunload = null;");
```