# Switching between two browser window using selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

When I click on an input button of a html page, new firefox window is opened.How can I switch between these windows using Selenium in Python? I need this in Python not Java.

Comment: possible duplicate of [WebDriver switch to new browser opened after click on button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9588827/webdriver-switch-to-new-browser-opened-after-click-on-button)

Comment: Thats in Java, I need in Python.

Comment: Have you tried porting the same code to Python?

Comment: Check this as well - http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#moving-between-windows-and-frames

Comment: I did try:
for handle in driver.window_handles:
 driver.switch_to_window('handle')
But its not working.

Comment: Could you post your url?

Comment: Apologies, i passed the handle as string not variable. 
Works well now.
Thank You.