# How to take the screenshot for the new window in selenium and after the screenshot is taken it should navigate back to the previous page

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have used the code below to take the screenshot for a new window, but it is taking the screenshot for the previous window.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/a")).click();  
Thread.sleep(15000);
File scrFile18 = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile18, new File("d:/Users/ Updates.png"));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
WebDriver driver;
driver=new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();//maximize
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);//wait
driver.get("http://www.dittotv.com/");//url
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[@alt='Windows']")).click();
String parentHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();

for (String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
    driver.switchTo().window(winHandle); 
}
File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("E:\\screenshot.jpg"));``
driver.close();
driver.switchTo().window(parentHandle);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to switch to the new window before taking screenshot. Please have a look at this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9597714/3122880)

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
    var fs = require('fs');

    var driver = new webdriver.Builder().build();

    webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.saveScreenshot = function(filename) {
        return driver.takeScreenshot().then(function(data) {
            fs.writeFile(filename, data.replace(/^data:image\/png;base64,/,''), 'base64', function(err) {
                if(err) throw err;
            });
        })
    };


    // example usage
    driver.saveScreenshot('mypage.png');
```