# Am automating a webpage which take time to load a page on clicking a link. Tried implicit and explicit waits,it is not working.Any other suggestions?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automation

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("xxxx")).click();
```

Clicking on the above link will take to another page. But it will take long time.
So while trying to find an element in the resulting page shows an error.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("yy")).getText();
```

I have tried Implicit and Explicit Waits, but it is not working everytime.

Comment: Have you switched to the newly opened window before waiting for a element to appear?

Comment: @Rameshwar yes..Actually it is not opening a new window. A new page will be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Use WebDriver wait. Put element which you need in 2nd page. Feel free to change any locator in below code :-

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 100);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("someid")));
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: @shubam jain I have tried the webDriverWait method, but it is not woking everytime I run the code. When the load becomes maximum in the website, the test case fails, because it is not finding the element after loading the page.

Comment: Shumbham Jain's solution looks good. Perhaps try increasing the waiting period.

Comment: @Rameshwar -> Thanks :) .. @kripindas-> please try to increase waiting period as Rameshwar said.. there is one more probability.. Is your 2nd page opening in a new tab... If Yes then you also have to switch to that page. for that you can refer :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9588827/webdriver-switch-to-new-browser-opened-after-click-on-button

Comment: If nothing works then use Thread.sleep(100000); .. But I want to tell you that is not a good practice to use that