# Unable to get new window handle with Selenium WebDriver in Java on IE

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, popup, webdriver

When I click a button on a page (in IE browser), a new popup page opens. My attempts to get the window handle for this popup have failed. Here is my first attempt:

```
String baseWin = driver.getWindowHandle();
System.out.println(baseWin);
Set<String>s = driver.getWindowHandles();
Iterator<String> ite = s.iterator();
while ( ite.hasNext() ) {
    String popUpHandle = ite.next();
    if(!baseWin.equals(popUpHandle)) {
        driver.switchTo().window(popUpHandle);
        System.out.println(driver.switchTo().window(popUpHandle).getTitle());
```

This attempt prints only the base window's handle, and if the second print statement is placed outside the if() statement, but within the while() statement and after the if() statement, it simply outputs the base window's title. So the set of handles only seems to contain the base window handle.

Here is my second attempt:

```
String baseWin = driver.getWindowHandle();
System.out.println(baseWin);
ArrayList<String> popUpWin = new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles());
popUpWin.remove(baseWin);
driver.switchTo().window(popUpWin.get(0));
System.out.println(driver.switchTo().window(popUpWin.get(0)));
```

This attempt returns an error, which says that the array popUpWin is empty, i.e. size == 0. So, the popup window's handle isn't being retrieved when I call driver.getWindowHandles() and only contains the base window's handle. Is this an IE issue? Is there a workaround? Or am I overlooking something in my code? (Note that I've neglected pauses in the code that I've included here, so I don't believe that is the issue.)

Comment: What version of selenium are you using? This is a known probelm for Windows 7 IE8 Selenium 2.12. But that's from lilke 2011

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are 2 things you need to do:

1. Change the security setting in IE browser:

   Open IE browser, click on "Internet Options" => "Security" => tick "Enable Protected Mode" for "Internet", "Local intranet", "Trusted sites" and "Restricted sites".

   This gives IE driver the capability to get control of the new window handle, so that when you call 
   `driver.getWindowHandles();` or `driver.getWindowHandles().size();`
   you will get all the handles including the original window and the new windows. To be more accurate, you just need to set the security setting for all 4 domains to be the same which means you can uncheck "Enable Protected Mode" for all 4 domains but it is discouraged obviously.
2. After you call `driver.switchTo().window(windowName);`, you need to add `((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.focus();");` before the IE driver can perform any actions on the window.

   This is because IE driver needs the window that it is working on to be at the foreground, this line helps the driver get the focus of the window so that it can perform any actions on window that you want.

The following is a complete sample:

```
    String baseWin = driver.getWindowHandle();
    //Some methods to open new window, e.g.
    driver.findElementBy("home-button").click();

    //loop through all open windows to find out the new window
    for(String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()){
        if(!winHandle.equals(baseWin)){
            driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
            //your actions with the new window, e.g.
            String newURL = driver.getCurrentUrl();
        }
    }

    //switch back to the main window after your actions with the new window
    driver.close();
    driver.switchTo().window(baseWin);

    //let the driver focus on the base window again to continue your testing
    ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.focus();");
```

Comment: I have tested the first option (enable protected mode) => works like a charm! Thanks

Comment: "Enable Protected Mode" - enabling nor disabling of this value for all zones not working for me. Any ideas?

Comment: UPDATE: CONDITION: Now I have tried this with selenium-java version 3.8.0 and IEDriverServer 3.8.0 but one more condition need to be meet: You have to load html page and from this html page you have to open new window with new page. If you open new tab/window by some another way, for example manually as new page or by addon (Flash and ActiveX I didn't test), this widow will maybe not be detected by Selenium! (my case) So it is working actually but be careful how are you opening new tab/page/window.

Answer (score 2):

please note Pop Up is not a new window its an Iframe treat it as IFrame `driver.getWindowHandles();` is for handling multiple tabs in browser its not for handling Iframe

you should use `driver.switchTo().frame()`  to switch into that pop up

Comment: Hi, there. This answer did not solve the problem. I wonder if I should be more specific. The "popup" is a second, separate IE window. driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id("id"))) is not successful, and entering a frame number, 0 or 1, is also unsuccessful.

Comment: is that page hosted on web can you share with me link ? lemme look into that my self