# Python using Selenium's WebDriver window_handles to switch between tabs - returning only parent window

Tags: python, selenium, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I'm writing automation with Python (3.6.5) and Selenium (3.141.0).
The webpage I'm visiting, opening a new tab, which I get to my driver.window_handles in Chrome and FF, but not in IE 11.

I tried to google.
The only solution I could find is:
[How to switch to the new browser window, which opens after click on the button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9588827/how-to-switch-to-the-new-browser-window-which-opens-after-click-on-the-button/45661220#45661220)

But it didn't work.

I tried to add 1 second of sleep but the result remained the same.

```py
handles = self.browser.window_handles
test.log('window handles: ' + str(len(handles)))
```

I expected the output to be 2, which I get in Chrome and FF but in IE I get 1.

Comment: Have you tried adding a wait for `len(handles) > 1`?

Comment: @JeffC yes, I also used WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.number_of_windows_to_be(2))
and nothing changed.

Comment: So the wait timed out or ?

Comment: There're some required configurations to set when using IEDriver, you can follow the [required configurations](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver#required-configuration) in this documentation and try it again. Also [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33510283/unable-to-get-new-window-handle-with-selenium-webdriver-in-java-on-ie) and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19777318/new-window-handles-disappearing-in-ie/19794327#19794327) can be helpful.

Comment: @JeffC timed out, yes.

Comment: @YuZhou I will try this and update. Thanks!