# Handle Webpage dialog box in selenium

Tags: ajax, selenium, selenium-webdriver, modal-dialog

I am automating an web application through selenium, in that application on click of Search button a web page dialog box appears.

This dialog box is not identified by developer tool, developer tools still identifies parent window.

Driver.getwindowhandles is returning count of 1, which looks like the dialogbox is not a child window.

Tried Alert, frames, iframes but none them has identifed this dialog box.

Also this popup is not a window pop up.

Can someone please suggest how to handle this kind of webpage dialog box. [image]

This is a nightly job, so i cannot use Robot class , AutoIT or sikuli because these require an active window session.

Comment: Did you tried javascriptexecutor?

Comment: Hi amrita, javascript executor? How to get element id because developer tool is not identifying the pop up. Can you please provide if you have any snippet?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33510283/unable-to-get-new-window-handle-with-selenium-webdriver-in-java-on-ie  try this