# Guarantee switching to a specific window in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I have googled and looked at this site for reference but all the answers I came across did not provide a guaranteed way to switch to a specific window.

---

I am using Java with Selenium and I trying to find a guaranteed way to switch between two windows (where the second window is from clicking a link that produces a pop up).

`driver.getWindowHandles()` creates a Set object and since the Set interface does not provide any ordering guarantees, how will I be able to switch to a specific window?

What I currently have is this:

```
public static void switchToPopUpWindow(By by) {
    driver.findElement(by).click();
    Set<String> handles = driver.getWindowHandles();
    if (handles.size() > 1) {
        for (String currentWindow : handles) {
            driver.switchTo().window(currentWindow);
        }
    } else {
        logger.info("There is only one window open...");
    }
}
```

However, since the ordering is not guaranteed, it won't always land on the window that I want. How can I guarantee a switch to the pop up window?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to switch to the new browser window, which opens after click on the button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9588827/how-to-switch-to-the-new-browser-window-which-opens-after-click-on-the-button)

Answer (score 0):

To switch to a second window, switch with an handle different from the current one:

```java
public static void switchToPopUpWindow(By by) {
    driver.findElement(by).click();

    String currentHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();
    Set<String> handles = driver.getWindowHandles();

    for (String handle : handles) {
        if (!handle.equals(currentHandle)) {
            driver.switchTo().window(handle);
            return;
        }
    }

    logger.info("There is only one window open...");
}
```