# webdriver how to switch to new window if old was closed

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I am pressing Continue to this website (not recommended) and window changes URL where I have to input password.
The window is opened, but webdriver do not see it "Unable to get browser"
How to make webdriver to "see" it and use it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to switch the driver to new opened window. Example code in java:

```
for(String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()){
    driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
}
```

My answer is based on this thread:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9597714/4855333

Answer (score 0):

if the driver did not open the window it can't "see it".