# Selenium switching to new Tab in IE

Tags: java, internet-explorer, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I am using selenium Java. I need to open new tab and open URL in the newly opened tab. I am try to using getWindowHandles, its working fine in google chrome, but the same code is not working for Internet Explorer. Please suggest the proper solution for this. Here is the code I have used.

```
WebDriver=new InternetExplorerDriver();
driver.get("https://google/com");
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL+"t");// Open new tab
driver.switchTo().window(driver.getWindowHandles().iterator().next());
driver.get("http://msn.com");
```

I also tried  following code, but not working.

```
ArrayList<String> tabs= new ArrayList<String> (driver.getWindowHandles());
driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(index));
```

**Note:** The same code working fine with google chrome, not working in IE only. IE version:IE10

Comment: IE is not picking the new tab as a window handle.

Comment: then we are not able to handle tab in IE, right?

Comment: After trying in many ways and googling this is what I got to open a new URL in IE,

`driver.get("https://www.google.com");
   driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL+"n");// Open new tab
   driver.switchTo().window(driver.getWindowHandles().iterator().next());
   driver.get("http://www.msn.com");`            



And I suggest you to complete the operations in first window and go to new one as we cannot switch back to the old ones.

Comment: I already tried with new window alos. actually while opening in new window, the same URL open in new window, while redirecting to new URL old window only getting redirected. Two windows have same URL (Google.com) at initially, it seems new url open in newly created tab. But actually ew URL opened in old window only

Comment: [check this](http://superuser.com/questions/69857/how-do-i-get-ie8-to-open-a-blank-page-with-ctrl-n)