# How to switch to new Browser Window?

Tags: java, selenium

I am doing automation of a application using selenium.

I am trying to switch to a new browser window. but my code get stuck in the line `driver.switchTo().window(winhandles)`.

It doesn't give any exception.

Comment: can you provide more code please, this can't help to answer?

Comment: What your  `window(winhandles)` winhandles have the value?

Comment: for (String winNames : windowSet) {
     
     try{
      mLog.debug("trying to switch to window: "+winNames);
                                 
       driver.switchTo().window(winNames);
       
      
      mLog.debug("Switched to :"+driver.getTitle()+" Window...");
     }catch(NoSuchWindowException ex){
      tempSet.add(winNames);
     }
    }

Comment: This is my code..

Comment: windowSet=driver.getWindowHandles();for (String winNames : windowSet) {
     
     try{
      mLog.debug("trying to switch to window: "+winNames);
                                 
       driver.switchTo().window(winNames);
       
      
      mLog.debug("Switched to :"+driver.getTitle()+" Window...");
     }catch(NoSuchWindowException ex){
      tempSet.add(winNames);
     }
    }

Comment: @BinduSharma do not write your code in comments. Remove your code from comments. Edit Your question and write that code there using "code block"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to switch to the new browser window, which opens after click on the button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9588827/how-to-switch-to-the-new-browser-window-which-opens-after-click-on-the-button)

Answer (score 0):

You can switch between windows as below:

```
// Store the current window handle
String winHandleBefore = driver.getWindowHandle();

// Perform the click operation that opens new window

// Switch to new window opened
for(String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()){
    driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
}

// Perform the actions on new window

// Close the new window, if that window no more required
driver.close();

// Switch back to original browser (first window)
driver.switchTo().window(winHandleBefore);

// Continue with original browser (first window)
```