# Switch to other site from main application

Tags: selenium-webdriver

In my current application, manually when i click on a Button say 'Buy' button it takes me to a different site within the same browser (in another tab). 
Usually I can switch to the Tab using

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

But while am doing it in automation the second site is opening in a different browser. How can i handle this. I want this to open within a the same browser like how its happening when i do it manually. Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You don't define the programming language, but in Java it is as follows:

```
// Store the current window handle
String winHandleBefore = driver.getWindowHandle();

// Perform the click operation that opens new window

// Switch to new window opened
for(String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()){
    driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
}

// Perform the actions on new window

// Close the new window, if that window no more required
driver.close();

// Switch back to original browser (first window)
driver.switchTo().window(winHandleBefore);

// Continue with original browser (first window)
```

Source: [How to switch to the new browser window, which opens after click on the button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9588827/how-to-switch-to-the-new-browser-window-which-opens-after-click-on-the-button)