# Windows Application Driver handle windows explorer window

Tags: appium, python-appium, winappdriver

I'm trying to automate a windows desktop application and everything is fine until in one of the steps in my application, I have to click on a "Browse" buttom that opens a windows explorer window to select an image and load it.

The thing is that I do not know how to make WinAppDriver focus in this new window, to be able to select the image and load it.

[image: Screenshot]

This is a part of the desktop application, and when sending click on Browse:

[image: Screenshot 2]

Answer (score 1):

You probably need winappdriver to change its current handle to the one from the new explorer window. I'm not sure about the Python syntax, but in C# you do it like this:

```
driver.SwitchTo().Window(Driver.WindowHandles.Last());
```

The `Last()` function just selects the most recent added windowHandle.
Make sure you keep your previous window handle around, so you can switch back once the explorer window closes.

Also take a look at these posts. Its about webdriver but the functions are similar:

[webdriver C#](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/3986/how-can-i-switch-to-new-window-using-webdriver)

[webdruver java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9588827/how-to-switch-to-the-new-browser-window-which-opens-after-click-on-the-button)