# How to switch windows in selenium? I want to enter gmail credentials on the new popup which appears, popup doesn't have a close button

Tags: selenium, popup, window, switching

```
def switch_to_new_window(self):
    sleep(5)
    print("Parent window title: " + self.webdriver.title)
    parentWindow = self.webdriver.current_window_handle
    childWindows = self.webdriver.window_handles
    for window in childWindows:
        if(window!=parentWindow):
            self.webdriver.switch_to.window(window)
            break
    sleep(2)
    print("Child window title: " + self.webdriver.title)
```

The above works for other popup windows but not for gmail popup window. The gmail popup window doesn't have a close button. [Gmail popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5LEQ.png)

Comment: did you try driver.close(), then driver.switch_to_default_content()

Comment: I don't want to close the window, i just want to enter gmail credentials in the new popup

Answer (score 0):

This is how I switch windows in java, there might be something similar in python.

`driver.SwitchTo().Window(WindowName);`

you may also want to check out this thread: [How to switch to the new browser window, which opens after click on the button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9588827/how-to-switch-to-the-new-browser-window-which-opens-after-click-on-the-button)

Again, its about java but might offer some help.

Answer (score 0):

In Python you can switch to popup window like this

```
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[x])
x would be 1
```

in your case if there is only one tab and window and then you need to get back to default window in order to avoid error

```
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[x])
x would be 0
```

the same it work for switching the tabs
hopefully it work